# how to match a fingerprint from database?

Tags: vb.net

i now able to save the fingerprint directly to database using this code...

```
   Dim fingerprintData As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream
    Template.Serialize(fingerprintData)
    fingerprintData.Position = 0
    Dim br As BinaryReader = New BinaryReader(fingerprintData)
    Dim bytes() As Byte = br.ReadBytes(CType(fingerprintData.Length, Int32))
    Dim cn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=dataBEST;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False")
    Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO fininger_table VALUES(@FIRSTNAME, @LASTNAME, @FINGERPRINT)", cn)
    cmd.Parameters.Add("FIRSTNAME", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = CaptureForm.tboxFname.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("LASTNAME", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = CaptureForm.tboxLname.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("FINGERPRINT", SqlDbType.Image).Value = bytes
    cn.Open()
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    cn.Close()
```

now ? how to retrieve that fingerprint and matches to the user ? btw my device is DIGITAL PERSONA..tnx in advance

Comment: Please put down your computer programming tools and find another profession. Computer programming is just not right for you.

Answer (score 0):

Should be fairly simple.

```
1.) Simply fetch the data of your fingerprint using SqlDataReader
2.) Store the fetched value to a variable
3.) compare your bytes() variable with the fetched value.
```

In case you are not familiar how to use a datareader, consider this function

```
 Function MSselectspecific(ByVal SQLComnd As String)
        Dim Sqlconn as New SQLConnection("your connection parameters")
        Dim sqlcommand As New SqlCommand(SQLComnd, Sqlconn)
        Dim reader As SqlDataReader
        Dim resulta As String = Nothing
        Dim x As Integer = 0
        Try
            Sqlconn.Open()
            reader = sqlcommand.ExecuteReader
            While reader.Read
                resulta = reader(0)
                x = x + 1

                Exit While
            End While
            Sqlconn.Close()
            If x > 0 Then
                Return resulta
            Else
                Return Nothing
            End If

        Catch ex As Exception
            Sqlconn.Close()
            MsgBox("Selectspecific Details Error    " & vbNewLine & ex.ToString)
            Return Nothing

        End Try
    End Function
```

And use it like this (along with the variable that holds your user fingerprint data)
*NOTE: bytes() is the part of your code that contains your fingerprint data ie (`Dim bytes() As Byte = br.ReadBytes(CType(fingerprintData.Length, Int32))`)

```
     if bytes() = val(MSSelectSpecific("select FINGERPRINT from fininger_table where FINGERPRINT = " & bytes() & ";")) then

     msgbox("Congrats! It's a match")
     End If
```

Note that I used val since you are comparing two numeric values.

Comment: tnx for the quick response..mate !

Comment: please tell us if this answer has helped you. If it has, consider accepting it as the correct answer. 'tis proper nettiquette.

Comment: and here..  if byte() = val(MSSelectSpecific("select FINGERPRINT from fininger_table where FINGERPRINT = " & byte() & ";")) then

     msgbox("Congrats! It's a match")
     End If..

it says..byte is a type and cannot be used as expression..why is that ?

Comment: I was actually referring to your bytes() variable, the one that holds your scanned fingerprint data

Comment: Edited the answer to reflect that.

Comment: u do familiar bout OTW SDK of DIGITAL PERSONA ?

Comment: No, unfortunately. I simply referred  to the code sample you made. Again, byte() is simply the variable you mentioned in the question. Refer to my edit.